# Crystal reports grouping by date, does not shows detail of records by the grouped date

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm having a problem with the records showed in the detail in which should be all the records grouped by the date field.

I want to group all the invoices done in one day, without doing it by day of the day, ex. Monday, Tuesday, etc.. That's not what I want, I want to show the Document Date (group) and the invoices sold in that date under it.

Please see the graphic attached, the detail record does not belong to the group.

I'm using Crystal Reports 14.1.5.1501

Thank you very much for your help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfGrj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT98P.png)

Added two more screens, to verify it's the same field.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7IsB.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD10i.png)

Comment: Can you describe your database used for this report.  Please list all of the tables used in the report and how those tables are joined.  Looking at the image you provided, it looks like you have a full join in your database query that should probably be a left join.

Comment: I do have two tables (Invoice), Master and Detail, joined for the DocKey field which is the main key. I cannot insert a image to the comment to show you, but here are the join info (inner join, Not enforce, =).

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can edit the original question to add additional information such as images.  Its usually a good idea to edit the question to provide updates like this anyways, as this ensures that the next person to read your question gets all of the information without having to wade through the comments to piece it together.  After an update, you can then drop a quick comment to notify us that you've answered a question left in a comment.

Comment: Added the second image. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: On what field do you group your records? On DocDate? On DocDueDate? Or which field value do you show? Looks like a simple mistake (using wrong field somewhere).

Comment: Yes, it looks like something easy to fix, but I can't get my head on it(I have checked like 10 times to see if it's the sam field). I attached two more screens showing the date field when I put my mouse over, in both, the group and the detail.
Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it!

Comment: What happens to your output if you change the Join Type to a `Left Outer Join`?  I'm having a hard time understanding the relationship between your two tables.

Comment: Hi!
Sorry for the delay, I've been busy these days, I tried that out too, but it did not work.
Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem, when creating the group, I did not notice that for some reason under "The section will be printed for each" drop down list, it brings "For each week" by default instead of  “For each day”. I created another report and the same thing happened, that's why it was driving me crazy. Like I said "It has to be something simple". I had to search for a youtube video to realize that.